# According to the Young Earth Creationism, did God wait or did God work for 6 x 24 hours non-stop?

Tags: creation, young-earth-creation

A. What I mean of "God wait" is :
God create anything instantly.
So, after He created something, He waited for almost 24 hours to do His next work.

B. What I mean 6 x 24 hours non stop is : 
It's not instantly, God work for 24 hours to create something.

If the answer is A
the question : why did He rest (pause) on each day of creation ?

If the answer is B
the question is : why did it take so long for Him to create ?

Answer (score 2):

God certainly could have created it all instantly.

Based on the verb forms, it appears some things were created instantly or very quickly:

> Genesis 1:3: And God said, “Let there be light,” and there was light.

Others suggest a more progressive act, but whether that was 1 minute or 24 hours, we can't say.

> Genesis 1:9: And God said, “Let the water under the sky **be gathered** to one place, and let dry ground appear.” And it was so.

Why did he pause each day (for however long that was) before creating? The usual explanation is that God was demonstrating the pattern of the healthy work week and Sabbath day of rest, i.e., God paused for our benefit.

> Exodus 20:11: For in six days the Lord made the heavens and the earth, the sea, and all that is in them, but he rested on the seventh day. Therefore the Lord blessed the Sabbath day and made it holy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, curiousdannii. Why I ask especially to the YEC, because I'm used to read in the internet an argument : if the bible say a day, then it's 24 hours. So, the verse _For in **six days** the Lord made the heavens and the earth_ following the same argument, the YEC answer to my question should be : God works **144 hours** to make the heavens and earth.

Comment: @karma They say that only in contrast to those who say it took God billions of years to create. They do not mean that God had to be actively creating all 24 hours each day. Why would he?

Comment: I understand that. It's just to me it seems the argument "if the bible say a day, then it's 24 hours" not strong enough :).

Comment: @karma There is a point where we need to ask ourselves: why does God wants us to read His Word? Most Christians will read the Bible for *teaching* about how God, humans, and the rest of creation are **related**, not for cold scientific description of how things work or how things were made.  Thus the description is primarily *functional*, not mathematical / astronomical / geological.  Therefore, if we only allow Gen 1 to speak in cold scientific terms, we are not letting God to teach us in what matters more: the teaching that **only God knows**, not the ones that we can investigate on our own.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple, I realize that want it or not, my confusion will be based from the knowledge I have. And the knowledge I have, some are from science, for example : the earth rotate on it's axis. Since YEC say _"if Bible say a day then it's 24 hours"_ ---> isn't this saying involved science in the reading of the verse ?

Comment: @karma You said "*isn't this saying involved science in the reading of the verse?*"  Answer: maybe, if you are a YEC.  But no one, and I believe not even God, forces you to read "day" like that.  Who told you to be a YEC?  We can be Christians without being a YEC.  There are other legitimate options to read Gen 1 and to STILL believe in that Gen 1 is inspired by God.  For example, Gen 1 can be read as Israelite theological response to a similar creation story which is much older and widespread, because the God in that story is very different than Israelite's God.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple, thanks for your explanation. It did enlighten me.